# areas of parts of the circle in a grid

Tags: geometry, circles, area

[image]
Same colored cells have equal areas. 
There is a grid consisting of ***NxN squares*** and a circle of Diameter ***N***.
How do I find areas of the circle in each cell of the grid for any ***N*** . AFAIK, calculating 1/4 grid is enough because of symmetry.

Comment: It is not an easy job: that's the [Gauss Circle Problem][1] [1]:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem

Comment: IS there any formula to find out area in a specific cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

The real challenge is for incomplete cells, of course.

You need to solve the integral

$$\int_a^b(\sqrt{1-x^2}-c)dx,$$ where $a,b$ correspond to verticals on the grid or to the intersection of the circle and the horizontal $y=c$.

$$I=\frac12\left.(x\sqrt{1-x^2}+\arcsin x-2cx)\right|_a^b.$$

Comment: $$ \dfrac{r^2\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{r}\right)+x\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}{2}-x+C $$

Comment: @Sparrow: you forgot the $c$ constant (and I forgot a $2$).

Comment: Its working well but I'm feeling it difficult to find area of red cell as mentioned in @mick s answer

Comment: @Sparrow: this involves the "or" clause in my second sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I will only work on the second given figure. The most difficult part is finding the area of the red region.

[image]

In the first supplied diagram above, $\angle POR = 60^0$, and A = [Orange region] = [sector OPR] – [⊿OSR].

By symmetry, B = A.

[Blue region] = $A \cup B$ = [sector OPQ] – [Green square]

[Red region] = $A \cap B =  A + B - A \cup B$